# Disposable class keeps reference

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm using simple DataReader commands very often in my project.
To simplify it, I've created a function:

```
Public Function DataReaderFromCommand(ByRef uCn As SQLite.SQLiteConnection, ByVal uCommandText As String) As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader

    Dim nCmdSel As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = uCn.CreateCommand
    With nCmdSel
        .CommandText = uCommandText
    End With

    Dim r As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = nCmdSel.ExecuteReader

    Return r

End Function
```

In my project I use it like this:

```
Using r As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = DataReaderFromCommand(cnUser, "SELECT * FROM settings")
    Do While r.Read
        'do something
    Loop
End Using'this should close the DataReader
```

In one case, I need to delete my database. However this fails with the error "File is locked by another process".

I tried to isolate the problem, and the locking occurs because of the function "DataReaderFromCommand".

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong / what keeps the database locked?

I thought that after "End Using" of the datareader, the SQLiteCommand would also be disposed, so there are no further reference to the database.

Comment: The connection also looks the db.

Comment: @Plutonix I know. I use "Using" for the connection.

Comment: We can only go by the code posted.  The connection and the command object are not closed or disposed there

Comment: @Plutonix I've attached a database, and I detach it before End Using for the connection is reached. I need more time to edit my posting to show this code. Thank you for the advice for now.

Comment: Commands (`SQLite.SQLiteCommand`) are also disposable.

Comment: Why are you passing the connection `ByRef`?

Comment: An ADO.NET connection object is a high-level, lightweight object. The actual database connection exists at a lower-level. That is how connection pooling can be implemented. Presumably the low-level connection is still open despite your ADO.NET connection object being closed. You may have to look at manipulating connection pooling to ensure that the low-level connection is closed when you want it closed. Be careful though, because you may also slow down your data access by requiring low-level connections to be opened more often.

Comment: @Enigmativity I pass ByRef in order to avoid a copy of the connection.

Comment: @tmighty - That doesn't do that for `ByVal` either. The only time ever that you need to pass `ByRef` is if the function you call in to needs to change the reference **back in the calling code**. You're not doing that so you don't need to do `ByRef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that not all the disposables are being disposed of.  We are assured that the connection passed to that helper is in a `Using` block, but the command also needs to be disposed of as it has a reference to the connection:

```vb
Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sql, dbcon)
```

Even if you dont use the overloaded constructor, in order to work, somewhere you set the connection property.  This illustrates one of the problems with such "DB helper" methods: the `DBConnection`, `DBCommand` and `DBReader` objects work together very closely, but they are created in different methods with different scopes and you can't normally see if everything is being cleaned up properly.

The code posted will always fail because that `DBCommand` object - and by extension the `DBConnection` - are not disposed.  But even if you clean up properly, pooling will keep the `DBConnection` alive for a while as [jmcilhinney explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872668/disposable-class-keeps-reference#comment78707385_45872668).  Here are 2 fixes:

#### Clear the Pool

```vb
Using dbcon As New SQLiteConnection(LiteConnStr),
    cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sql, dbcon)

    dbcon.Open()
    Dim n As Int32 = 0
    Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rdr.Read
            ' == DoSomething()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}  ==  {1}", n, rdr.GetString(0))
            n += 1
        End While

    End Using

    ' Clears the connection pool associated with the connection. 
    ' Any other active connections using the same database file will be 
    ' discarded instead of returned to the pool when they are closed.
    SQLiteConnection.ClearPool(dbcon)
End Using

File.Delete(sqlFile)
```

The `dbCon` and `cmd` objects are "stacked" into one `Using` statement to reduce indentation.

This will close and discard any and all connections in the pool, **provided** they have been `Disposed` - as well as any objects which reference them.  If you use `Dim cmd ...` you will need to explicitly dispose of it.

#### Force Garbage Collection

I think this is much more ham-fisted, but it is included for completeness.

```vb
Using dbcon As New SQLiteConnection(LiteConnStr),
    cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sql, dbcon)
    ...
    Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ...
    End Using
End Using

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

File.Delete(sqlFile)
```

This also works as long as everything has been properly disposed of.  I prefer not to mess with GC unless absolutely necessary.  The issue here is that clean up will not be limited to DBProvider objects but anything which has been disposed and is awaiting GC.

Yet a third workaround would be to turn off pooling, but you would still have to dispose of *everything*.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the nCmdSel wasn't disposed. I was hoping it would automatically be released when the reader is "End Using"'ed.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be trying to do it this way:

```
Public Sub UsingDataReader(ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal commandText As String, ByVal action As Action(Of SQLite.SQLiteDataReader))
    Using connection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
        Using command As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand(commandText, connection)
            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                action(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Then you can call the code like this:

```
UsingDataReader("/* your connection string here */", "SELECT * FROM settings", _
    Sub (r)
        Do While r.Read
            'do something
        Loop
    End Sub)
```

This ensures that all of the disposable references are closed when the `Sub` has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to also close your `cnUser` connection to the database.

Closing/disposing the reader does not necessarily close/dispose the open connection.

Comment: Yes, I do that. I use "Using" for the connection.